# One potentiometer supplying two effect units

Tags: power-supply, power, parallel

How can i do this?

I want a simple expression pedal splitter where one expression pedal can be used to control two effects units. I don't want to setup a additional powersupply or digital potentiometers.

I had tried simply disconnection the supply on one effect unit and driving it with the voltage from the other unit.That worked ok for two 3.3volt units, or two 5 volt units.

However, now i have one effects unit uses 5volts and the other uses 3.3volts. I thought some Schottkey clipping diodes like in the schematic would do the trick, but it seems to be clipping at about 4 volts rather than 3.3v. Why would that be? Though I think there must be a limiting resistor for this constant current but a voltage drop cannot be allowed in this circuit else full modulation of an effect will not occur.

The 27K resistor is needed because this particular 3.3volt effect unit will not modulate with a simple varying supply on the tip of the control jack, but must also have a small load as would be expected if an expression pedal was connected to it. Most effects are not like that, but this one is.
Can this be done.

Also, it is not known whether someone might use two 5v units, two 3.3 volt units, or a 5v & 3.3v, and in any order.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could run into unseen problems especially if you are routing a signal through the potentiometer. I'd use a dual potentiometer like this: -

[image]

Then there is never any doubt that both pedals work together (whether enabled or not) but on independent circuits. Of course if you decide you want to chain 3 or 4 pedals then use this: -

[image]

Comment: Wow, I've never seen a quad potmeter before! I didn't know they existed :-)

Comment: @MartinF: Stereo fader.

Answer (score 0):

When your pot wiper is turned to the max then the top diode is forward biased and you are feeding 5 V into the 3.3 V supply through the diode. You will either pull down the 5 V supply or bring the 3.3 V supply high.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fimqzv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. An alternative single-pot approach.*

Just feed the wiper output to the 0 - 5 V output. Use a 5:3.3 attenuator to feed the 0 - 3.3 V output. R4 provides the 27k load required on the 3.3 V device.

I've chosen R2 + R3 to be 10 x R1 so that they don't load the pot significantly.

Andy's stereo pot is a better solution.

Comment: We posted the same solution at the same time...

Comment: Ah, but mine has an editable schematic! When you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar the schematic gets saved in line - no account - no screengrab - no gridlines.

Comment: I see. I thought that was the idea of the clipping diodes, to prevent voltages higher than the supply? What if there was a series resistor between the wiper and the junction of the diodes?

Comment: That would protect the 3.3 V supply but you'd then get 0 - 5 V out on both sockets and destroy the 3.3 V ADC. Draw a schematic and you should see it.

Answer (score 0):

With the schematic you posted: When the pedal is at 100%, you will put 5V through the the top clipping diode, straight into the 3.3V of the other FX unit. That's not a good thing. Depending on how the 3.3V FX is built, the 5V might damage it, or (most likely) the 5V FX will never reach 5V, but get stuck around 3.3V (this might be the 4V you noticed where clipping occurs). In short: This schematic will not work.

You might want to try this:
[image: Schematic1]

I'm not sure if it will work, because I don't know what the FX's look like on the pedal input. I also don't know if your pedal is 10k, or something else. If it's higher, you might want to take higher values for R2 and R3 (take R2=10*Rpedal for instance). You can use [this website](http://www.ohmslawcalculator.com/voltage-divider-calculator) to calculate resistor values, or (even better for learning), calculate them yourself:

Vout = Vin * (R3 / (R2 + R3))
Where Vout = 3.3V and Vin = 5V

An other good option would be to use a stereo pedal, as @Andyaka suggested.

Comment: thanks. I should have explained further. It is not known whether someone might use two 5v units, two 3.3 volt units, or a 5v & 3.3v, and in any order.

Comment: @brownt: Please add this new information to the initial question (use the edit button).